# How to Create a List Based on Criteria & Exclude Duplicates

Tags: if-statement, indexing, excel-formula

I'm working on a excel formula to create a list based off different criteria but I am trying to figure out how to also have to exclude duplicate values from column G. Below is my formula.

`=+IFERROR(INDEX(ETIP!$G2:$G500,SMALL(IF((ETIP!$Q2:$Q500=$C$3)*(ETIP!$D2:$D500=$A$1),ROW(ETIP!$D$2:$D$500)),ROW(1:1))-1,1),"")`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to `UNIQUE()` and `FILTER()`?

Comment: @P.b using unique breaks the function and doesnot work the correct way

Comment: `=Unique(filter(range, (your_condition1)*(your_condition2)),,1)` in your case probably `=UNIQUE(FILTER(ETIP!$G2:$G500,(ETIP!$Q2:$Q500=$C$3)*(ETIP!$D2:$D500=$A$1)),,1)`

Comment: Or if you don't want to exclude duplicates, but show distinct uniques, don't use the final `1` in the formula: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(ETIP!$G2:$G500,(ETIP!$Q2:$Q500=$C$3)*(ETIP!$D2:$D500=$A$1)))`

Comment: @P.b thanks for your input but this did not work. Gave me "#CALC" & "#SPILL" errors

Comment: Spill error means that the result overlaps a cell that isn't cleared. If you click the cell containing the error you would see the size of the spill result (blue lines around the range). Make sure these cells are cleared.